# What Websites/Newsletters/Organizations/Methods Are Recognized for Keeping Up With And Gaining Experience In New Software/Technology?

Tags: software-industry, work-experience, technology, websites, software-engineering

I apologize in advance if this question is not relevant or against the rules, but I'm really hoping you can help me with this as I'm really not sure where else to turn to. If this is not the place for it, then once again I apologize and hope you can point me to the correct place to ask this question. :)

I was recently interviewed by a man who asked me 'how do you keep up with the latest changes in Technology'?

I had previously read the post on this Stack titled '[Why do interviewers ask "How do you keep abreast of changes in technology"?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12573/why-do-interviewers-ask-how-do-you-keep-abreast-of-changes-in-technology)', and I had come prepared with the answer 'By following key individuals and organizations on Twitter and reading further into the topic if it interests me.'

I was not expecting him to receive that answer poorly. The impression I got was that there was some secret way of doing so that I was not aware of, and he didn't really answer my question about how I would be able to improve on that or gain relevant experience in the industry that would be recognized by employers in general.

So I've come here to ask:

1. What Websites, newsletters, and organizations are recognized and prestigious sources of information for new developments in the industry?
2. How do I gain relevant industry experience in those new fields that would be widely recognized? Online courses and github projects don't really seem to be widely recognized (at least not according to him), so I'm in a bit of a Catch - 22 here: How do I gain experience in new technologies if I need that experience to be hired in the first place?

Comment: Twitter, in particular, is not exactly a respectable information source...

Comment: @AnonAnon, The answer depends on the specific computer languages or frameworks that you are being interviewed for. There are too many websites and sources to list here. Furthermore, it is also subjective to say which websites are more useful than the others.

Comment: @keshlam, okay, so then what is? Everyone here keeps downvoting and criticizing my question without actually answering it. :( If this is the wrong place to ask, is it really so hard to tell me where else I can ask my question?

Comment: @Job_September_2020 , is there a website that will aggregate the latest developments in the industry in general, and that is respectable? :)

Comment: @AnonAnon Have you heard of StackOverflow? It sounds like you are looking for an authoritative site that acts like your teachers. Because the field is so fragmented and because it is undergoing so many new developments, there is no one place aggregating the latest developments. New ideas show up in conference papers, requests for comments, and in internal developments kept secret so as to have a competitive advantage. Noone can pull all that together.

Comment: @AnonAnon To add to that, take a look at all the conferences and journals published by A.C.M. and IEEE. There is no way for anyone to even read all of them and understand them.

Answer (score 1):

There often is a secret answer to this, which is "the same way you do!" only you don't know what way the interviewer does. There are a number of bad answers, like "I don't know I never thought about that."

But the real key is that this, like many other interview questions, is not a simple-fact-you-correctly-answered question. If I ask "what is your favourite colour?" there are not more points for "green" than for "red." What matters is the explanation that follows. (This means the title of your question at the moment, asking for sources of this info, is not the right question.) To give a better answer, think about this: Why do you rely on Twitter for this? Why don't you read blogs, take courses, go to conferences, read books? (Or maybe you do and didn't mention it?) Can you tell a story about a time you read a tweet about [thing] so then you watched the video and then you tried [thing] on a hobby project and found out it was great/terrible and then were able to use that knowledge at work? **That's** an answer an interviewer will like even if they're not fond of Twitter.

If you spend your own money (buying books, subscribing to Pluralsight) this may be seen as more positive than doomscrolling on twitter or watching whatever youtube's algorithm chooses to offer you. But I wouldn't spend money learning for no reason other than to tell an interviewer I had done so.

Comment: All right... then what is a good blog to follow up on, and where can I get news of conferences that emphasize up-to-date topics? It's so frustrating that everyone here keeps saying 'Twitter is not a good source'. I KNOW it is not a good source, but why won't anyone on here tell me what is a good source? Look, I give up... just tell me where else to go where I won't be mocked for not knowing the answer to a question I'm asking.

Comment: Explanation: ABSOLUTELY. Especially if you've got a nondirective interviewer, who is just going to give you the chance to tell them about yourself rather than feeding you a lot of specific questions. You need to be able to tell a story about why you find this interesting, what you have done to actively start trying to learn it, what successes you've had along that path, challenges you've overcome in doing so. It isn't factoids that land the job, it's being someone who has a history of creatively exploring possibilities and solving problems.

Comment: I didn't say "Twitter is not a good source." In fact it's an important source for me to keep up. I said the **explanation** of why you use a source, examples of what you get from it, examples of "further reading", and a **story** of how you discovered something specific with this technique, connecting it to a thing in your job, is far more important than twitter vs Scott Hanselman's blog vs a YouTube channel. The specific source you start with is no more important, really, than your favourite colour. Your current response is weak regardless of what the first word (your source) is.

Answer (score 1):

If your entire answer to the question was:

> 'By following key individuals and organizations on Twitter and reading
> further into the topic if it interests me.'

Then you didn't answer the question. You needed to provide names and examples.

> What Websites/Newsletters/Organizations/Methods Are Recognized for
> Keeping Up With And Gaining Experience In New Software/Technology?

It depends.

The list for people programming databases will be different than the one for front end developers, which will be different than the one for big data developers, which will be different than the one for AI/ML developers, which will be different than the one for interplanetary space mission developers.

If I was interviewing you, and I had a similar background I would recognize some of your list. I would expect to ask a followup question based on your list. If you weren't specific then that part of the interview ended rather quickly.

Comment: All right, do you have a list of Websites/Newsletters/Organizations that are better than Twitter for keeping up with the latest tech developments? I'm sure there are, I just don't know what they are.

Comment: The problem is that there are too many of them. If you have a more specific question -- a field that you are interested in -- then you can fairly easily answer this question with a bit of websearching. If you're going to leave it as "all possible tech developments", no answer is adequate. Consider what you actually want to specialize in, and look for resources on those specialties. Don't expect the data to come to you, go out and actively find it. Don't wait for blog posts -- or at most wait only until you see something interesting go by, then go dive into that for a while.

Comment: The problem with your answer to the interviewer is the same as the problem with your question: It shows no effort to actually seek out information, provides no hint of what you might or might not be good at or want to be good at, and leaves the other person wondering whether you actually want to make an effort or have someone else make the effort for you.